# Value error in convolutional neural network for shape input

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am facing a problem using a convolutional neural network using Keras with Tensorflow as backend with Anaconda Python.

While defining my CNN and compiling, an error occurs:

```
def cnn_model():
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same',
                 input_shape=(3, 48, 48),
                 activation='relu'))
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same',
                 activation='relu'))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same',
                 activation='relu'))
    model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(NUM_CLASSES, activation='softmax'))
    return model
```

The error that I get is:

> File
>   "C:\Users\pandey\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py",
>   line 113, in _standardize_input_data
>       'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
>
> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_10_input to
>   have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (0, 1)

I am using channel first in Keras and have defined the data format as channel first in starting only.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Pimusa thanks, i am a newbie into this... Please suggest what improvement should i do in code

Comment: While loading  the data i got that error

Comment: uptill above i get no problem unless i add the below code